# Mongodb col1+col2 like '%test%'

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Hi guys can we do something like this in mongodb

> col1 + col2 like '%test%'

as I have to search for the presence of test in collection having schema

```
collection = { "col1" : "sds" , "col2" : "est" , "col3" : ""}
```

Comment: Is your question that you want to find "test" in either col1 **or** col2, or are trying to concatenate the values and find the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
db.collection.find( { $where: "/^.*test.*$/.test(this.col1 + this.col2)" } );
```

In this case the regular expression `/test/` should work as well.

Of course mongo has to do a full scan over all documents since there is no option to use an index.

[MongoDB doc $where](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want concatenation:

If you are trying to concatenate and still want to use an index, which you probably do at least to find where "col1" and "col2" exist, as trying to concatenate something that isn't there would end up in horrible errors.

Consider the set, a bit better as concatenation will match test:

```
{ col1: "sdst", col2: "est", col3: "abc"}
```

Use aggregation with the [$concat](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) operator and [$regex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) in the [$match](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/):

```
db.test.aggregate([
    // Find the rows you can concatenate -- uses index
    {$match: { col1: {$exists: true}, col2: {$exists: true}} },

    // Concatenate the strings and retain the original columns
    {$project:{
        col1: 1,
        col2: 1,
        col3: 1, 
        newcol: {$concat: [ "$col1", "$col2" ]}
    }},

    // Match the required strings in the concatenated result
    {$match: { newcol: {$regex: "test", $options: "i"} } },

    // Restore the original document fields only    
    {$project: { col1: 1, col2: 1, col3: 1 }
])
```

That still can't use an index for anything after the initial match, but it is one better than [$where](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/), which will kill any chance of using an index at all.

If you mean that you want to find "test" in either of "col1" and "col2" then that's easy, just use [$or](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) in your query to find.

```
db.test.find({ $or: [ { col1: "test" }, { col2: "test" } ] })
```

Or $regex if you have to find it in strings. Note that $regex is not very efficient if you are not looking from the start of a string, as in: "^test"